# onClick events not firing inside iOS Instagram In App Browser Meteor React JS Web App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, instagram, inappbrowser

I have discovered a bug on a site that we produced and I cannot figure out how to debug. Currently attempting to debug using GhostLab app.

**Issue**

When visiting this website inside the iOS Instagram in app browser, any onClick events are not functioning.

App functions perfectly on mobile safari, desktop browsers.

**Header ICON Code**

```
<i className="fas fa-shopping-bag" onClick={() => this.props.activeCartDropdown()} />
<i className="fas fa-bars" onClick={() => this.props.activeHeaderDropdown()} />
```

**FAQ Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link, NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

import history from '/client/history';

class BrandAmbassadorFAQ extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className={`faq ${this.state.open}`} onClick={() => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })}>
        <div className="question">
          {this.props.question}
        </div>

        <div className="answer">
          {this.props.answer}
          {this.props.image &&
            <img src={this.props.image} className={`img-fluid ${this.props.image_size ? this.props.image_size : ''}`}/>
          }
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BrandAmbassadorFAQ;
```

App Details & Versions

```
Meteor 1.8.0.2
React 16.4.2
@babel/runtime 7.3.1
```

Comment: Can you try moving the icons into `button` and adding the `onClick` to the button instead?

Comment: Have attempted that. Any onClick events across the site have ceased functioning [including product detail Add to Cart which are buttons]. I also added `cursor: pointer` to the CSS

Comment: Currently downgrading `@babel/runtime` to the following: `@babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55` to see if it has something to do with the _babel_ version and the **arrow function** inside the `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading `@babel/runtime` from `7.3.1` to `7.0.0-beta.55` solved the issue. Will continue to monitor.